# variable value to be used as formula for another cell

Tags: excel, vba, scripting

I have an issue using Formula property to update the cell value. Can any of you please help me with this. I have explained the issue using the details below.

`Worksheets("Overall_Status").[C11].Formula = "=Sheet_Name!C10"` inserts the `=Sheet_Name!C10` in the cell. But I want to use the value that is present in that variable and update the value as formula.

Ex:
Sheet_Name!C10 has "Joe" as value and so i need Overall_Status!C11 = Joe!C10. This formula will update the details from C10 to C11.

I am creating the Joe sheet based on the name of the employee that is entered in another cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
Worksheets("Overall_Status").[C11].Formula = _
          "='" & Sheet_Name.Range(C10.Value) &  "'!C10"
```

Comment: Thanks Tim. That works. I have done a similar thing. `Worksheets("Overall_Status").Cells(lRow + 1, 4).Formula = "='" & Sheet_Name & "'!C10"`